# Laravel distincted script mechanics call

Tags: php, laravel

I am pretty much beginner in programming. Since few weeks I've been using Laravel framework. So far, I was using ajax and redirects to reach the functions in controller through Routes. Someone told me that it is wrong to use redirects and so many ajaxes in Views. So how do I call these functions and all mechanics in a proper way then? I read the documentation not for the first time but I still dont get it. Could someone explain it to me a little bit please?

This is an example how do I use views with controller. 
viewfile.blade.php:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ineedthisfunction",
    data: {

    },

        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        },

        error: function(error) {
            alert('error');
        }
});
```

routes:

```
    Route::post('/ineedthisfunction', 'Controller@thisfunction');
```

controller:

```
public function thisfunction(){
return "some returned value from script";
}
```

I am doing this everytime I need to use any php code. Or I am writing it inside of views. They tell me both are wrong. What do I do then?

Sometimes instead of ajax i just do: "header("location:/ineedthisfunction"); But i think it is horrible idea to.

Comment: Please provide a sample of code you have that illustrates your question.  It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: @watcher Okay, sorry for that. Already edited

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned redirects in your question, but I don't see any redirects in your controller method.  In general, if you're going to make an AJAX call then sending a redirect response isn't going to do you any good.  The browser itself isn't going to receive the redirect and navigate the user to the new page, your Javascript callbacks are going to be triggered with a status code of 301 (or 302, depending).  Taken that way, redirecting in response to an AJAX request just doesn't make any sense.

You have a chance in your controller method to make a choice, however, on what to return.  Is the request an AJAX request? Then return *something*.  If not, then you can easily return your redirect:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// ...

public function thisFunction(Request $request)
{
    if($request->wantsJson()) {
        // Return data to ajax request
        return response()->json(['key' => 'value']);
    }

    return redirect()->to('/some/url');
}
```

Without some more context of what you're trying to accomplish I'm afraid I can't be more specific.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I guess that my question is confusing. What i mean is that i do not know how to work on framework. I know that in views we have views, and in controller are scripts and mechanics. Since I need to use these scripts and functions every few lanes I was writing them in View documents or calling them noone knows why by AJAX or any other methods, coz I dont know how to to it other way. It seems pretty simple to me. Views>ajax>routes>controller>answer. But i was overusing it, and doing it when its not needed coz i dont know any other ways